# Rails/Ruby one-liner unless zero/nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

Is there a way to make this situation more compact in rails views?

Eg I have haml

```
= object.count unless object.count ==0
```

I sort of don't like that has I'm repeating the function there, I would much rather have something like

```
= object.count unless ==0
```

Eg if I had more complex statements

```
= object.relations.where(attribute: "something").count unless zero?
```

I could split that into two lines say

```
- cnt = object.relations.where(attribute: "something").count
= cnt unless cnt==0
```

But for each situation I would have multiple lines, and storing a variable to use once sucks.

EDIT: just to elaborate I want to check if the number is 0, and if so not display anything. It looks nicer in the view that way.

***UPDATE:***

One of the answers made come up with a solution along these lines

```
class Object
  def unless
    self unless yield(self)
  end
end
```

So I can call whatever object I have with a block eg. `.unless{|c| c<1}`

This lets me tack the conditionals on, and keeps it pretty clear what is going on :), bonus is as it's block driven I can use this on any object :P.

Thanks everyone :)

**UPDATE EVEN MORE**

Having `|c|` in the block sucked. So I looked up the api and changed it too

```
class Object
  def unless(&block)
    self unless instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

So now I can use .count.unless{zero?} to accomplish this :P. Or if I have a complicated condition I can add that in with `|c|` etc.

Comment: This kind of stuff should not be done in the view anyway: `object.relations.where(attribute: "something").count`. For the simple stuff I don't see a problem repeating `object.count`. `unless == 0` or `unless zero?` is not possible. You will always have to do something with `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only about `count`, you can monkey patch `Enumerable`:

```
module Enumerable
  def count_or_empty_string
    self.any? ? self.count : ''
  end
end
```

If `object` is an enumerable, you can do this:

```
= object.count_or_empty_string
```

This will return an `""` if `object.count == 0` else it will return an integer. So there is no need for `unless` or `if` in your HAML anymore.

Comment: That's pretty damn close to what I was after. You put me on the line to come up with a general version that I can pass a block into :). I'll post that into my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If object is an array you can use `object.empty?` (or `object.any?` for the reverse case)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. count is from activerecord and will always return a value. I basically want to hide that value if it's zero. An empty field looks better than displaying 0 in the table.

Comment: you can still write something like = object.count if object.any?

Comment: The point was its ugly and repititous. I can easily accomplish something like.

Comment: The point was its ugly and repititous. I can easily accomplish something like.

    = object.relations.where(attribute: "something").count unless object.relations.where(attribute: "something").count==0

but that is long, as written in the question I can split this into two lines, but it's still unsatisfying if I have 6 odd locations I'm collecting the count from, 6 variables this would get ugly quick.

Comment: @user1570690 - You can remove the repetition by monkey patching `Enumerable`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a view helper:

```
def display_count_or_nothing(array)
  array.count unless array.count == 0
end
```

In the view you can use it like this:

```
<%= display_count_or_nothing(array) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the following is nice and clear, although i hate the variable "object",
it would be much nicer if the name of the variable described the contents of the array (as plural)

```
= object.count unless object.empty?
```

Comment: I don't think his variable name is really `object`... this code is just an example to illustrate his problem.

Comment: Correct. Object was so you didn't get carried away with the actual name of the object or its purpose